# Condicional en Array para datatables

Tags: php, array

Tengo un array definido para imprimir un datatables pero me gustaría que en la parte de los botones (posición 0 del array) no mostrase la opción de borrar o desactivar cuando se de un tipo de dato concreto, en mi caso, que cuando el usuario sea administrador no se pueda desactivar pero no sé como ponerle un condicional dentro del array... Any idea?

Mi código:

```
    while ($reg=$rspta->fetch_object()) {
        $data[]=array(
            "0"=>($reg->estado)?'<button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" onclick="mostrar('.$reg->idusuario.')"><i class="fa fa-pen"></i></button>'.' '.'<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="mostrar_clave('.$reg->idusuario.')"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></button>'.' '.'<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="desactivar('.$reg->idusuario.')"><i class="fas fa-toggle-off"></i></button>':'<button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" onclick="mostrar('.$reg->idusuario.')"><i class="fa fa-pen"></i></button>'.' '.'<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="mostrar_clave('.$reg->idusuario.')"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></button>'.' '.'<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="activar('.$reg->idusuario.')"><i class="fas fa-toggle-off"></i></button>',
            "1"=>$reg->nombre,
            "2"=>$reg->apellidos,
            "3"=>$reg->codigo_persona,
            "4"=>$reg->email,
            "5"=>"<img src='../../admin/files/usuarios/".$reg->imagen."' height='50px' width='50px'>",
            "6"=>$reg->fechacreado,
            "7"=>($reg->estado)?'<span class="label bg-green">Activado</span>':'<span class="label bg-red">Desactivado</span>'
            );
    }
```

Comment: ¿Y como defines al admin? ¿como sabes si ese user lo es? Es decir, algo asi como $reg->role->admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que sabes si un usuario es el admin mediante un valor booleano en este campo `$reg->admin`, una posible solución pasaria a ser esta:

```php
while ($reg=$rspta->fetch_object()) {

    $desactivar0 = ($reg->admin) ? '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="desactivar('.$reg->idusuario.')"><i class="fas fa-toggle-off"></i></button>' : '';

    $activar0 = ($reg->admin) ? '<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="activar('.$reg->idusuario.')"><i class="fas fa-toggle-off"></i></button>' : '';

    $valor0 = ($reg->estado) ? '<button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" onclick="mostrar('.$reg->idusuario.')"><i class="fa fa-pen"></i></button>'.' '.'<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="mostrar_clave('.$reg->idusuario.')"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></button>'.' '.$desactivar0 : '<button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" onclick="mostrar('.$reg->idusuario.')"><i class="fa fa-pen"></i></button>'.' '.'<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="mostrar_clave('.$reg->idusuario.')"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></button>'.' '.$activar0;

    $data[]=array(
        "0" => $valor0, 
        "1" => $reg->nombre,
        "2" => $reg->apellidos,
        "3" => $reg->codigo_persona,
        "4" => $reg->email,
        "5" => "<img src='../../admin/files/usuarios/".$reg->imagen."' height='50px' width='50px'>",
        "6" => $reg->fechacreado,
        "7" => ($reg->estado)?'<span class="label bg-green">Activado</span>':'<span class="label bg-red">Desactivado</span>'
        );
}
```

Seguramente querrás hacer más cambios, pero es para que cojas la idea y la apliques.

Ya nos diras si te sirve.

Comment: Claro, con una variable en el array, bien visto... demasiadas horas delante de la pantalla, voy a ello, gracias

Comment: es perfecto, muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido :-)  Saludos!

Comment: Un detalle solo... que escondas eso no va a impedir que un usuario avanzado encuentre las funciones desactivar() y activar() en tu codigo javascript, y mediante la edición del inspector de su navegador inyecte el código necesario para ejecutarlas. Del mismo modo, tambien cualquier usuario podria cambiar el id que les pasas a todas las funciones javascript para cambiar cosas de los otros usuarios. Te recomiendo que siempre verifiques al usuario a nivel de servidor por si acaso hay algun listillo (lo digo por si no lo haces)

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, de momento con esto me vale, es para evitarme llamadas a soporte de que han desactivado el usuario con privilegios y no pueden logarse en el backoffice...

Comment: Solo un detalle curioso, agrega los campos cuando el booleano es valor 0... ¿no debería ser con valor 1 que es cuando es true?

Comment: He estado haciendo pruebas y detecto ciertos comportamientos raros segun el valor de $reg->admin... si les pones otro numero lo interpreta como 1, y cosas asi... casi que te pediria que hicieras la comprobación de este modo:  `($reg->admin === 1)?` por si $reg->admin coge otros valores no previstos. Por lo que acabo de leer por ahi, 0 siempre es false, pero 1 u otro numero se evalua como true, asi que mejor fuerza que sea 1 por si acaso

Comment: OK, ahora probaré, gracias de nuevo...